# Azure Active Directory using wrong Application Client ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I developed an Azure web app that was using Azure Active Directory on my subscription for authentication but I am now trying to switch from my test AAD directory to the actual AAD I want to use on another subscription. I am getting the following error:

> AADSTS50020: User account 'MyAccount' from external identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/a26def89-f7e6-4496-b4cb-7ffee9ddbabf/' is not supported for application '025ef17e-9767-4f4e-a1b1-6218491d94ed'. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant. Please sign out and sign in again with an Azure Active Directory user account.

The tennant ID is correct but the application Client ID is not what I am putting in my App Settings and it's not even the correct Client ID that I am using for this deployment. I have two different Applications added under my Azure Active Directory account and this Client ID belongs to a different one. I do not understand where the site is grabbing this from. After searching my solution I found it embedded in the Web Deploy for a different publishing profile, not the one I have been publishing from. I commented out this reference and unchecked Enable Organizational Authentication when publishing to see if that would change anything and it hasn't.

I am using the standard AAD code that Visual Studio 2015 creates when you create a new MVC application and check to use Work or School accounts that provides the following AppSettings:

```
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="6b0dde38-55e6-4801-ba14-58708ecb5c06" />
<add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
<add key="ida:Domain" value="new.domain.imtryingtouse" />
<add key="ida:TenantId" value="a26def89-f7e6-4496-b4cb-7ffee9ddbabf" />
<add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="mysite.azurewebsites.net" />
```

I have verified through FTP that the correct ClientId in AppSettings is in my web.config on the server but it's not the one being used in that error message.

Any help would be appreciated. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to brady gaster I was pointed to the Configure Azure AD Authentication option accessed by right clicking the project. By going through this wizard and then publishing it was able to set up the authentication correctly. I'm not sure what this does differently than changing the app settings in web.config but it worked.

[image: Configure Azure AD Authentication]

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the PMs at Microsoft on the Web Tools Extensions crew, building out Azure tools. I have a few questions about your repro here. When you execute the publish experience, are you specifying the destination client id you want to use? I understand you're developing against AAD App #1, but you want your app to use AAD App #2 once you've published it. Are you providing the Client ID of the destination AAD App during publish? If you are, it should replace the Client ID of the one you're developing against to the one you want to run against.

Also, which version of VS are you on, and which version of the Azure SDK do you have installed? That would help troubleshoot this. It'd also help to know if you're using a DreamSpark or CSP Azure subscription or if your subscription was one you set up on your own via a free trial, then pay-as-you-go or MSDN subscription. Some of the subscriptions have a variety of service availability so that would be helpful to know if you're willing to share the information.

If you'd prefer to discuss this via email rather than on SO, we can facilitate that, too. Either way I will post either a resolution or action plan if this requires customers to update VS or if we have an issue that we need to resolve in a later release.

Thanks for that info, we'll work through this and get you unblocked.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I'm not sure how to see what my subscription type is. It's being provided to me by my company and I know it's not a trial. I am using version 2.7 of the Azure SDK. When I publish, as far as I can tell, there is no dialog specifically for Client ID in the wizard. The way I am providing the Client ID is through the web.config which I have confirmed is what is on the web.config on the server.

Comment: I'm emailing you now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup for one of my customers. So far running "Clean Solution" from the "Build" menu inside of VS2015 has solved it for me.

Comment: No change. Must be something else. Thanks though.

Comment: Just to make sure nothing is being cached when you build your solution after changing the web.config, you could delete the obj and bin folders inside of your project folder. Just be sure to have a backup ready in case something goes wrong.